# How to get tweets from twitter without login in twitter

Tags: android, twitter, tweets

I want to get tweets from https://twitter.com/twitterapi this link without login,
I am using "twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar" library for twitter integration,
I don't want user to be login for getting tweets

is anybody have done this, please help me

Comment: Not possible without Login!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialgiri.app see this app , may be your comment will be change

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get answer and it is possible to get data from twitter without login
refer below link
http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/08/get-public-tweets-from-twitter-api-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get tweets (and other info) without requiring the user to login by using the Application-only authentication.

Just follow the steps here:  https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only